# Netflix keeps disappearing from the status/notification bar (S5)

Tags: notifications, netflix

I use the Netflix app on my phone to stream to chromecast. Ever since the update, Netflix doesn't stay open in the drag down status/notification bar so I can pause the show I'm watching, etc. The notifications are turned on in the app and in the  notification settings, even on the lock screen. But once the phone is locked, it disappears. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Netflix.

Answer (score 1):

I have a GS7, and I was looking for this answer when I ended up figuring it out myself. Go into your phone settings and to notifications and make sure they are turned on for Netflix. Then the app will be able to show in your notification bar.